# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2

Tags: python

I am creating XML file in Python and there's a field on my XML that I put the contents of a text file. I do it by

```
f = open ('myText.txt',"r")
data = f.read()
f.close()

root = ET.Element("add")
doc = ET.SubElement(root, "doc")

field = ET.SubElement(doc, "field")
field.set("name", "text")
field.text = data

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("output.xml")
```

And then I get the `UnicodeDecodeError`. I already tried to put the special comment `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` on top of my script but still got the error. Also I tried already to enforce the encoding of my variable `data.encode('utf-8')` but still got the error. I know this issue is very common but all the solutions I got from other questions didn't work for me.

**UPDATE**

Traceback: Using only the special comment on the first line of the script

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lse\createxml.py", line 151, in <module>
    tree.write("D:\\python\\lse\\xmls\\" + items[ctr][0] + ".xml")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 820, in write
    serialize(write, self._root, encoding, qnames, namespaces)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 939, in _serialize_xml
    _serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 939, in _serialize_xml
    _serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 937, in _serialize_xml
    write(_escape_cdata(text, encoding))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1073, in _escape_cdata
    return text.encode(encoding, "xmlcharrefreplace")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 243: ordina
l not in range(128)
```

Traceback: Using `.encode('utf-8')`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lse\createxml.py", line 148, in <module>
    field.text = data.encode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 227: ordina
l not in range(128)
```

I used `.decode('utf-8')` and the error message didn't appear and it successfully created my XML file. But the problem is that the XML is not viewable on my browser.

Comment: It would be useful to see the entire error message to see where it's coming from. In the meantime try using `decode` instead of `encode`.

Comment: Updated, it successfully created my XML when I use `decode`, but the file is not viewable on my browser.

Comment: Note that using `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` serves only to insert non ASCII characters in the python sources. It doesn't affect encoding/decoding of strings in any way. Also, if the file `myText.txt` isn't ASCII you should use `codecs.open` and provide the right encoding: `codecs.open('myText.txt', 'r', 'utf-8')`.

Comment: Additionally, you should add an encoding to `tree.write` if your text is not just ASCII (see also the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write))

Comment: Might have been a non-breaking space. Just saying. Option + Space on Mac. 0xC2 0xA0 in UTF-8.

Comment: @kagat-kagat: Did one of the answers solve your problem? If so, please accept it to mark the question as resolved.

Comment: @superlukas, it could be any 2-byte UTF-8 encoded character - See all characters that lead with `0xC2`: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Answer (score 69):

You need to decode data from input string into unicode, before using it, to avoid encoding problems.

```
field.text = data.decode("utf8")
```

Answer (score 12):

I was running into a similar error in pywikipediabot. The `.decode` method is a step in the right direction but for me it didn't work without adding `'ignore'`:

```
ignore_encoding = lambda s: s.decode('utf8', 'ignore')
```

> Ignoring encoding errors can lead to data loss or produce incorrect output. But if you just want to get it done and the details aren't very important this can be a good way to move faster.

Comment: Do note that ignoring encoding errors will potentially lose data, or produce incorrect output.

Answer (score 11):

**Python 2**

The error is caused because ElementTree did not expect to find non-ASCII strings set the XML when trying to write it out. You should use Unicode strings for non-ASCII instead. Unicode strings can be made either by using the `u` prefix on strings, i.e. `u'€'` or by decoding a string with `mystr.decode('utf-8')` using the appropriate encoding.

The best practice is to decode all text data as it's read, rather than decoding mid-program. The `io` module provides an `open()` method which decodes text data to Unicode strings as it's read.

ElementTree will be much happier with Unicodes and will properly encode it correctly when using the `ET.write()` method.

Also, for best compatibility and readability, ensure that ET encodes to UTF-8 during `write()` and adds the relevant header.

Presuming your input file is UTF-8 encoded (`0xC2` is common UTF-8 lead byte), putting everything together, and using the `with` statement, your code should look like:

```
with io.open('myText.txt', "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = f.read()

root = ET.Element("add")
doc = ET.SubElement(root, "doc")

field = ET.SubElement(doc, "field")
field.set("name", "text")
field.text = data

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("output.xml", encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<add><doc><field name="text">data€</field></doc></add>
```

Answer (score 1):

`#!/usr/bin/python`

`# encoding=utf8`

Try This to starting of python file