# load .json into python; UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, json

I am trying to load a json file into python with no success. I have been googling a solution for the past few hours and just cannot seem to get it to load. I have tried to load it using the same `json.load('filename')` function that has worked for everyone. I keep getting :
`"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in postion 124: invalid continuation byte"`

Here is the code I am using

```
import json
json_data = open('myfile.json')
for line in json_data:
    data = json.loads(line) <--I get an error at this.
```

Here is a sample line from my file

```
{"topic":"security","question":"Putting the Biba-LaPadula Mandatory Access Control Methods to Practise?","excerpt":"Text books on database systems always refer to the two Mandatory Access Control models; Biba for the Integrity objective and Bell-LaPadula for the Secrecy or Confidentiality objective.\n\nText books ...\r\n        "}
```

What is my error if this seems to have worked for everyone in every example I have googled?

Comment: You'll overwrite data in each step of the loop. Maybe you want to use `+=` instead of `=`...

Comment: Why are you loading each line separately? Try `data = json.load(json_data)`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I want to parse each line and store topic,question and excerpt separately

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
json.loads(line.decode("utf-8"))
```

Similar question asked here: [UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508539/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xc2)

Edit:
If the above does not work,

```
json.loads(line.decode("utf-8","ignore"))
```

will.

Comment: I am getting the same error after adding .decode("utf-8")

Comment: this seems to have allowed the file to load! (Y)

Comment: How would you do this with the load() method instead of loads()?

Answer (score 0):

If method answered by Academiphile doesn't work try this:

```
with open('path/to/file.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    model = json.load(file)
```

Adding it to open() function allows doing it with with json.load() function.